# Slovenian Municipalities - right spelling

Tags: carto, geocoding, slovenia

I'm working on Slovenian Municipalities. Matching them with georeferencing only hits around 80 pct. I have then tried MunicipalityId, but it doesn't work at all. Where can I get the list of names on municipalities, used by CartoDB, so I can make a reference dataset?

Answer (score 1):

You can download [this dataset from Natural Earth Data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.zip) and open the SHP as a layer in QGIS, for example.